# dropdown menus keep sliding down (repeatedly)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have surfed the internet for a while now trying to fix this issue. A video of what is happening can be found:

https://i.gyazo.com/59fc489b6099b513c41aedeed482b8d2.mp4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop().slideDown(300);
    $("dropbtn1").html("Products &#9650;");
  });
  $(".dropdown1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").slideUp(300);
    $(".dropbtn1").html("Products &#9660;");
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #939393;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn0">
      <li>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown1">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn1">Products &#9660;</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">HR System</a>
        <a href="#">Inventory</a>
        <a href="#">CMS</a>
        <a href="#">Project Management</a>
        <a href="#">Todo list</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

So quite obviously I need it not to repeat itself. I have applied fixes such as using mouseenter/mouseleave instead of hover and the callback function. When you do it to just the one drop down menu, it works flawlessly, but once you hover over all of them similar to what you see in the video, it messes up.

Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: That is not the correct video my man

Comment: The URL to your video has been concatenated and is therefore broken

Comment: Oh that's my bad guys, please try again :p

Comment: You can try $(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop(true, true).slideDown(300); and $(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop(true, true).slideUp(300);

Comment: Adding .stop to the slideup has actually solved the issue! Can you post an answer please, thank you

Comment: Tbh it looks really sattisfying to watch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try .stop

```
$(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop(true, true).slideDown(300); and 
$(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop(true, true).slideUp(300)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css (without animation), if it fits you...

```css
.dropdown3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown1:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #939393;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn0">
      <li>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown1">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn1">Products &#9660;</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">HR System</a>
        <a href="#">Inventory</a>
        <a href="#">CMS</a>
        <a href="#">Project Management</a>
        <a href="#">Todo list</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown1").hover(function() {
      if ($(this).children(".dropdown-content").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).children(".dropdown-content").slideUp();
        } else {
           $(this).children(".dropdown-content").slideDown();
        }
  });
});
```

This method checks if the `.dropdown-content` is visible and decides whether to `slideDown` the dropdown or `slideUp`